# duplicate identical items is csproj

Tags: c#, asp.net, csproj

Does csproj with duplicate identical items will do an action twice?

```
<Compile Include="Dashboard\Default.aspx.designer.cs">
<Compile Include="Dashboard\Default.aspx.designer.cs">
```

Comment: I think it would just not be valid, but why would you want to compile the same thing twice?

Comment: @BenRobinson: OT: To double-check it's really error-free. *lol*

Comment: i had to combine two huge csproj and I guess there might be some duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually will throw an error like so

```
error MSB3105: The item "Default.aspx.designer.cs" was
specified more than once in the "Sources" parameter
```

If I really have to double check I just do another incremental build after a full build to look for errors as the output is considerably smaller next time around